# finding the conditional probability that outcome of the second trial is $1$, without any explicit calculations

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability

**question:** Consider an **unending** sequence of **independent** trials, where each trial is equally likely to result in any of the outcomes $1$, $2$, or $3$. Given that outcome of the first trial is $1$, and outcome $3$ is the last of the three outcomes to occur, find the conditional probability that outcome of the second trial is $1$, **without any explicit calculations**.

let

1. $A_1$ = outcome of first trial is one
2. $A_2$ = outcome of second trial is one
3. $\text{third last}$ = outcome three occurs after outcomes one and two have occurred.
4. ${A}$ denote the **unending** sequence of **independent** trials, where each trial is equally likely to result in any of the outcomes $1$, $2$, or $3$.

what needs to be found is $P(A_2|A_1 \cap \text{third last})$, **without any explicit calculations**

**My reasoning is as follows**:

1. given that outcome $3$ is the last of the three outcomes to occur, we are now reduced to working with a **subset** $A$ where **only** outcomes $1$ and $2$ can occur.
2. this subset of $A$ *may* itself be an unending sequence of *independent* trials.
3. since outcomes $1$ and $2$ were equally likely in $A$, they should be equally likely in this **subset** of $A$ where **only** outcomes $1$ and $2$ can occur.
4. now, the probability that outcome of the second trail is one is $0.5$ (since there are only 2 outcomes, each of which are equally likely)
5. also, information about the outcome of the first trial won't change this probability, since the first and second trials are still independent.

hence, $P(A_2|A_1 \cap \text{third last}) = \dfrac{1}{2}$, but the given answer is $\dfrac{1}{3}$.

**edit:**

1. $1,2,3,2,1,2,...$ is an example where the outcome of the first trial is one
2. $2,1,2,2,1,3,1,...$ is an example where outcome $3$ is the last of the three outcomes to occur
3. $1,1,2,2,1,2,3,2,1.....$ is an example where the outcome of the first trial is one and outcome $3$ is the last of the three outcomes to occur

**edit2:** to summarize all answers and comments

1. let $X_i=j$ denote that outcome $i$ occurred for the first time at the $j^{th}$ trial. Then,what I wanted to find was $P(X_2 \neq 2\mid X_1=1, X_3>X_2)$, but what I ended up calculating is $ P(X_2 \neq 2\mid X_1=1,X_3\neq 2)$ -- JMoravitz
2. $P(A_2|A_1 \cap \text{third last}) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ is is not true because there must be a $2$ between $1$ and $3$. This means there is no symmetry between outcomes $1$ and $2$ anymore for the second trial. -- cr001
3. Knowing $3$ is the last of the numbers to appear does at each moment, that $2$ has not yet appeared, slightly skew the numbers in favor of $2$ next appearing as though it were *"fated to appear"*. -- JMoravitz

Comment: but the answer is $\dfrac{1}{3}$. have a look at the "my attempt" section of this problem--->https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3796570/415432. if it were true that $P(\text{one 2nd}|\text{one 1st}\cap \text{third last}) = \dfrac{1}{2}$, then the answer in the "my attempt" section would have been correct. but it is not.

Comment: It is not so easy to understand the question. For me, "one 1*st*" makes no sense, and { "one 1*st*" } is the set with one element that i do not understand. Then the information "*Given that outcome of the first trial is 1, and outcome 3 is the last of the three outcomes to occur,*" is also hard to digest. Which is exactly the probability space and which are the events? Do we really need the "whole" space $\{1,2,3\}^{\Bbb N}$ or it is enough to consider rather $\{1,2,3\}^{\{1,2,3\}}$? And in this case i would make the one of the tho sets rather $\{A,B,C\}$, so that $3$ and "three" differ...

Comment: "1,2,2,3,2,1,..." is an example of outcome 3 is the last of the three outcomes to occur. let me edit the problem to add a bit more clarity.

Comment: ... Please edit the problem, best maybe by using the probability space $\{A,B,C\}^{\times 3}$, the cartesian product of three copies of $\{A,B,C\}$. If i manage to guess the message of the question, then the three events are connected to the "patterns" $A??$ (first one), $?A?$ (second one), and third one... i have no guess.

Comment: Ah, well spotted by the person in the linked question.  Yes, I retract my earlier comment.  Knowing $3$ is the last of the numbers to appear does at each moment that $2$ has not yet appeared slightly skew the numbers in favor of $2$ next appearing as though it were "*fated to appear.*"  It is probably easiest to convey with a full formal approach.

Comment: @dan_fulea since you seem confused by the problem statement still., consider the experiment of rolling a fair three-sided die with sides $1,2,3$ repeatedly in sequence until all three sides have been seen at least once.  Letting $X_i$ be the random variable denoting the position in the sequence corresponding to the first occurrence of side $i$ the question is to find $Pr(X_2=2\mid X_1=1, X_3>X_2)$.  The OP's flawed argument was that $Pr(X_2=2\mid X_1=1,X_3>X_2)$ should be equal to $Pr(X_2=2\mid X_1=1,X_3\neq 2)$

Comment: *Independence* means that the outcomes of  trials $1$ and $3$ have no effect on the probabilities for trial $2$. The answer therefore is ${1\over3}$, and there is no sophisticated arguing necessary in order to confirm this value.

Comment: @JMoravitz i was trying to force a clear statement, after the example with "1,2,2,3,2,1,..." i had a clear guess, the OP has now a readable quality. But i am still unhappy with the "third last" notation for an event. I posted an answer, trying to give an alternative language for the events, one that arguably helps in such cases. (No "generating series" however...) In "third last" there is no way of thinking that it means "$3$ first after the occurrences of both $1$ and $2$"... not my mative language, but finding good names for the events would simplify much of the troubles.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter It is indeed the case if the "conditional independence" is proven. Each trial is independent but the event "3 occurs the last" which is equivalent to "1,2 does not occur last" is a separate thing and it is unclear the conditional independence holds. As the result indicates it indeed is true but is not trivial at all.

Comment: Actually to make things clear, the "conditional independence of  $1$ and $2$" is false given "$3$ is the last to occur and $1$ is the first to occur". The independence of "$1$" and "$3$ is the last to occur and $1$ is the first to occur" is true but not trivial to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A_2|A_1 \cap \text{third last}) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ is not true because there must be a $2$ between $1$ and $3$. This means there is no symmetry between outcomes $1$ and $2$ anymore for the second trial.

Consider the extreme sub-case where the experiment ends in exactly $3$ trials. In this sub-scenario, the second trial has a probability of $1$ to result in an outcome of $2$, not $1\over 2$.

Of course, the above sub-case is not the whole sample space and the calculation of this probability is not simple. To do this you need to sum up an infinite amount of things, scaled by each case's probability.

The easy way is to go for Bayes Theorem to solve the original problem.

In the Bayes Theorem way, we have

$$P(A_2 \cap A_1 | \text{third last})\cdot P(\text{third last})$$ $$=P(\text{third last}|A_2 \cap A_1 )\cdot P(A_2 \cap A_1 )$$

Notice, $$P(\text{third last})={1\over 3}$$
$$P(\text{third last}|A_2 \cap A_1 )={1\over 2}$$
$$P(A_2 \cap A_1 )={1\over 9}$$

Notice, the second equality comes from the fact that outcome $1$ cannot be last and there is a complete symmetry between outcomes $2$ and $3$.

Comment: I understand, that if the experiment consisted of a **finite** number of trials, then the probability that the second trail gives the outcome $2$ would not be $\dfrac{1}{2}$(after conditioning). my confusion (probably) stems from the fact that there is an  
 **infinite**  number of trials still left after conditioning. and an outcome of $2$ could appear in any of those infinite trials

Comment: You are correct in stating that infinite is different from finite. The key point is that since symmetry does not exist any more the infinite case is extremely hard to calculate and is not $1\over 2$.

Comment: For an intuitive understanding of why $P(\text{one 2nd}|\text{one 1st}\cap \text{third last}) ={1\over 3}$, roughly speaking it is because $P(\text{two 2nd}|\text{one 1st}\cap \text{third last})$ eliminates the extra constraint immediately so there is one less $1\over 2$ to consider and therefore it has twice as many chances as $P(\text{one 2nd}|\text{one 1st}\cap \text{third last})$. However this is not a formal proof. For a formal proof I believe the best way is to go for Bayes Theorem to solve the original problem first and work backward.

Comment: could you clarify your last comment a little bit. which extra constraint is eliminated immediately? what do mean by "one less $\frac{1}{2}$ to consider"?

Comment: Assuming we are in the space where $3$ is the last outcome, consider the two scenerios separately: (1) If $1$ is the second outcome, then the third number cannot be $3$ and the length of the string until a $3$ appears is at least $4$, with the additional constraint that there must be a $2$ somewhere. (2) If $2$ is the second outcome, then we can have all length $3$ and length $4$ strings in our sample space, which gives twice as many as in case (1).

Comment: Notice that the "twice" I stated need to be calculated for any length, up to infinity and sum them up, so it is hard to calculate directly.

Comment: A list of the length $5$ strings would be : case (1) 11213,11123,11223 case (2) 12113,12123,12213,12223. You can see case (2) has more chance of occuring than case (1). Notice the probability gets close to (1) when you increase the length, but the proability of reaching that length is decreasing, so after the infinite summation the result should converge to $1\over 3$.

Answer (score 0):

So if i correctly understand, the total space is based on $\Omega_0 =\{1,2,3\}$ and is $\Omega_0^{\Bbb N}$. An element in this space will be identified with a word in the alphabet $\Omega_0$. Measurable sets starting with a finite word $w$ followed by any other completions will be denoted by $w*$. So $122113*$ is the measurable set of all words starting with $122113$. I will use a question mark for one and only one digit/"letter" among $1,2,3$.

Then the OP deals with the events $A_1=1*$, $A_2=?1*$, and $T=1^+2\{1,2\}^*3*\ \cup\ 2^+1\{1,2\}^*3*$. Here, $1^+$ is a pattern for a non-empty word built out of ones, and $\{1,2\}^*$ is a (possibly empty) word built out of $1,2$.

We split the space $A_2\cap T$ explicitly in the pieces:
$$
\begin{aligned}
B &= 11\; \{1\}^*\;2\;\{1,2\}^*\; 3*\ ,\\
C &= 21\; \{1,2\}^*\; 3*\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $B\sqcup C=A_2\cap T$, and the needed conditional probability is $p$ below, and we compute...
$$
\begin{aligned}
p&=
\frac{\Bbb P(B)}{\Bbb P(B)+\Bbb P(C)}\ ,
\\[2mm]
\Bbb P(C) 
&= \Bbb P(21\; \{1,2\}^*\; 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot\Bbb P( \{1,2\}^*\; 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot\left(\sum_{k\ge0}\left(\frac 23\right)^k\right)
\cdot\Bbb P( 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot\frac 1{1-\frac 23}
\cdot\Bbb P( 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot\frac 1{1-\frac 23}
\cdot\frac 13\ ,
\\[2mm]
\Bbb P(B) 
&= \Bbb P(11\; \{1\}^*\;2\;\{1,2\}^*\; 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot\Bbb P(\{1\}^*\;2\;\{1,2\}^*\; 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot
\left(\sum_{k\ge0}\left(\frac 13\right)^k\right)
\cdot\Bbb P(2\;\{1,2\}^*\; 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot
\frac 1{1-\frac 13}
\cdot\Bbb P(2\;\{1,2\}^*\; 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot
\frac 1{1-\frac 13}
\cdot
\frac 13
\cdot
\Bbb P(\{1,2\}^*\; 3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot
\frac 1{1-\frac 13}
\cdot
\frac 13
\cdot
\left(\sum_{k\ge0}\left(\frac 13\right)^k\right)
\cdot\Bbb P(3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot
\frac 1{1-\frac 13}
\cdot
\frac 13
\cdot
\frac 1{1-\frac 23}
\cdot
\Bbb P(3*)
\\
&= \frac 13\cdot\frac 13\cdot
\color{blue}{
\frac 1{1-\frac 13}
\cdot
\frac 13}
\cdot
\frac 1{1-\frac 23}
\cdot
\frac 13
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{So we have the proportion $\Bbb P(C):\Bbb P(B)$ equal to $1$ : $\color{blue}{\frac 12}$.}
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{Finally:}
\\
p&=\frac{\Bbb P(B)}{\Bbb P(B)+\Bbb P(C)}
=\frac{\color{blue}{\frac 12}}{\color{blue}{\frac 12}+1}=\frac 13\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This was written in detail for a quick pattern reading. To see the result at a glance, one has to realize which is the (blue) factor making the difference.

---

It is the blue part when we compare:
$$
\begin{aligned}
B &= \color{green}{11}\; \color{blue}{\{1\}^*\;2}\;\{1,2\}^*\; 3*\ ,\\
C &= \color{red}{21}  \; \{1,2\}^*\; 3*\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(And the green / red parts have the same contribution.)